# responsive bootstrap 4 cols for all devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a responsive profile page for all devices so I used the bootstrap 4 grid system to divide the page for my needs I wanted the page to look like this:-[image: this] in desktops and like this:-[image: this]

so what I have tried is col-sm to work responsibly with small screens 
code snippet

```css
/* Profile Main Page Cards , holders...etc */
.holderTitle{
 font-family: hana;
 font-size: 34px !important;
 color:black !important;
 text-align: center !important;
}
/* Profile Image Thubmail */
.ProfileAvatar{
 border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Gray border */
 border-radius: 4px;  /* Rounded border */
 padding: 5px; /* Some padding */
 width: 150px; /* Set a small width */
  }
  /* Add a hover effect (blue shadow) */
.ProfileAvatar:hover {
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
  }
.holderText{
 color:black !important;
}
.messagebtn{
 text-align: center !important;
 font-family: hana !important;
}
.fontawsomeBIO{
 font-family: hana !important;
}




/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops  ( large Mointer )
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
 /* Profiler Card and Container (Profile Holder) on large Screen */
 .profileholder{ 
  width:45%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
  }
  
  /* 
 ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
 ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
  */
  
  @media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
 
 .profileholder{
  width:70%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 } 
  }
  
  /* 
 ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
 ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
  */
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
 
 .profileholder{
  width:95%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 } 
  }
  
  /* 
 ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
 ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
  */
  
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
 .profileholder{
  width:75%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 } 
  }
  
  /* 
 ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
 ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
  */
  
  @media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
 .profileholder{
  width:85%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
 }
  }
  
  /* 
 ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
 ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
  */
  
  @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
 .profileholder{
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
 }
 /* ProfileHolder Ends Here */
 /* Profile Content Card And Container  */
 .ProfileContent{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 } 
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Responsive Profile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\profile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><!-- Bootstrap CDN Font-awesome -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="card profileholder">
     <img class="card-img-top ProfileAvatar" src="..\upload\tmp\img.jpg" alt="alt"></img>
     <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title holderTitle">الإسم</h4><br><br>
      <a name="PMbutton" id="private" class="btn btn-danger btn-block messagebtn" href="#" role="button">رسالة</a>
      <a name="d" id="ds" class="btn btn-dark btn-block messagebtn" href="#" role="button">متابعة</a>
      <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fas-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-auto">
  <br>
   <div class="card ProfileContent">
    <div class="card-body">
    Content Here tab panel....etc
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

**advise :- show code in full page**

at least the most important thing is the right container under the col-sm-auto <--- tag well contains a tab panel the panel will have more than 4 tabs which is a lot to fit all screen width in smartphones so the panel will have an x-scrolling any suggestion to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap gives you some built in media queries by which you can define your layout.

- Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px) No media query
  since this is the default in Bootstrap
- Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up) @media (min-width:
  576px) { ... }
- Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) @media (min-width: 768px) {
  ... }
- Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) @media (min-width: 992px) {
  ... }
- Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) @media
  (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

You can use mobile first approach to design your layout. Starting from 0px to 575px will be stated first than as you move higher in the resolution you can use media queries to handle your layout. The class  col-sm-6 gives you ability to use 6 cols in a row. If you want that col to shrink at large desktop design to 4, you can add col-lg-4 besides col-sm-6. In this way your design will become responsive.

[image]

As far as the tab panel is consider, it depends upon your design. You can also apply nested technique or media list approach to handle your design on different resolution. Please consider bootstrap documentation for complete guidance. You can change col-sm-auto to  col-sm-6 as well.